# How to write a query to calculate number of items sold by dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables (Product and Order) like this:

**Product Table:**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

**Order Table:**

| id | user_id | product_id | date | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-07-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2022-07-02 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2022-07-01 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2022-07-02 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2022-07-03 | 12 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 2022-07-05 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 2022-07-05 | 1 |

**expect table**

| Name | 2022-07-01 | 2022-07-02 | 2022-07-03 | 2022-07-04 | 2022-07-05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 3 | 12 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

How to write a MySQL query to get the result like the 'expect table'

Comment: Use "pivot" as one of the keywords when searching. This is one of the most-asked SQL questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Mysql, reshape data from long / tall to wide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2255640/90527)", "[How would you solve this tricky SQL problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/710941/90527)"